# Is it possible that the Vuetify fullscreen dialog reaches the header without covering it? VueJS

Tags: vuejs2, modal-dialog, vuetify.js

I am using VueJS with [Vuetify 1.3.0](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start).
I have noticed that the [dialog in fullscreen mode](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs#example-fullscreen) serves me a lot, but the problem is that it covers everything and I would like it to only cover the footer and the body but not the header.

Is it possible (in some way) to make the [fullscreen dialog](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs#example-fullscreen) only appear in a section and hide everything in it?

Answer (score 2):

You can override the class: specifically the "top" property

```
.v-dialog--fullscreen {
 border-radius: 0;
 margin: 0;
 height: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 overflow-y: auto;
 top: 100px; //Depending on the header height you want to show.
 left: 0;
}
```